# linking pre-commit hook to VSC source control

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, version-control, eslint, githooks

My goal is that every time I git commit, `eslint` should run first. Currently, I'm using husky hooks.

When I commit through the terminal with `git commit -m "some message"`, it's working as expected.

The problem is when I'm using the source control in Visual Studio Code (or webStorm).

[image]
[source control commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcRLg.png)

When I commit like this, `eslint` won't run.

This is the husky pre-commit file: [husky pre-commit file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4t1V.png).
[image]
This is the package.json script section: [package.json script section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a20h0.png)
[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. It is preferred to post code in text instead of the image of the code. [Why we do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [vsCode issue with husky](/q/71423089)

Comment: did you find any fix for this ? I'm facing the same issue. Husky doesn't seem to run when using vs code source control!

Answer (score 1):

installing husky with [recommended steps](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=automatic-recommended) seems to works for me:

```
 From github.com:rachOS/BonApp-FRONT
 * branch            feature/create-user-account -> FETCH_HEAD
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/feature/create-user-account refs/remotes/feature/create-user-account
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- /home/rach/Documents/Code/BonApp/front-bon_app.ts/src/entities/Recipe.ts
> git cat-file -s 96fa250abd168e2175cffe887b14db1f5787e7dc
> git show --textconv :src/entities/Recipe.ts
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git ls-files --stage -- /home/rach/Documents/Code/BonApp/front-bon_app.ts/src/entities/Recipe.ts
> git cat-file -s 96fa250abd168e2175cffe887b14db1f5787e7dc
> git show --textconv :src/entities/Recipe.ts

> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 validate
> npm-run-all --parallel  check-format lint build


> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 lint
> eslint --ignore-path .gitignore -c .eslintrc --ext .ts --fix .


> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build


> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 check-format
> npm run format -- --list-different


> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 format
> npm run prettier -- --write  "--list-different"


> front-bon_app.ts@0.1.0 prettier
> prettier --ignore-path .gitignore "**/*.+(js|ts|json|jsx|tsx|css|html)" "--write" "--list-different"

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

src/adapters/primary/components/Form/Form.jsx
  Line 103:3:   'readOnly' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 137:45:  'type' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars

src/adapters/primary/components/Signup/manager/SignupManager.jsx
  Line 4:10:  'signup' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  59.19 KB  build/static/js/2.58d43881.chunk.js
  1.63 KB   build/static/js/3.90fad592.chunk.js
  1.55 KB   build/static/js/main.5cbbd48f.chunk.js
  1.17 KB   build/static/js/runtime-main.63262bbd.js
  1.14 KB   build/static/css/main.8636b64b.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/feature/create-user-account refs/remotes/feature/create-user-account
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- /home/rach/Documents/Code/BonApp/front-bon_app.ts/src/entities/Recipe.ts
> git cat-file -s 96fa250abd168e2175cffe887b14db1f5787e7dc
> git show --textconv :src/entities/Recipe.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed husky for my react app. I simply followed the instructions from the official guide [Getting started |  husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/getting-started.html). As I am using `yarn`, I specifically followed the steps from the `yarn` section [Yarn 2 install](https://typicode.github.io/husky/getting-started.html#yarn-2)

1. Install `husky`

```
yarn add husky --dev
```

2. Enable git hooks

```
yarn husky install
```

3. Install the hook you want - in my case I wanted husky to run `npx pretty-quick --staged`

```
yarn husky set .husky/pre-commit \"npx pretty-quick --staged\"
```

4. To have Git hook enabled after install edit `package.json`. You will need this if you plan to clone the repository and run `yarn install`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "husky install"
  }
}
```

After this, I committed my changes using VS Code source control. To verify if the `husky` pre-hook was working I checked to `Git` logs. You can find them in the `Debug Console` (open it with `Shift+Escape`), go to the `OUTPUT` tab and select the `Git` option from the dropdown menu.

[image]